# Gem & load image file error

Tags: ruby, image, rubygems, gtk

i did a desktop application, i am using gtk. I convert to my
application gem project. My gemspec file like this

```
s.name        = 'project_name'
s.version     = '1.0.0'
s.files       = ['lib/editor.rb', 'lib/utils.rb', 'lib/messages.rb',
'lib/lang.rb','lib/images/subhead.png']
.
.
```

i build it as gem and i installed it as gem. OK. I try on irb, require
'editor' but it gives me error. Std_error is

```
GLib::FileError: Failed to open file 'lib/images/subhead.png': No such file or directory from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/..
```

Why? i use png file in editor.rb. And it gives me error. How can i fix
it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/...` to see if the file is there?

Did you include the image file in the gem?

On its face, the error is very straight forward - there is no file where it expects one. So, try to figure out why that file isn't there inside the gem.

Comment: but i added image file at s.files[... 'lib/images/image.png'...] Is it wrong? How can i do?

Comment: But is the file actually there, or is it missing (from the gem you installed)?

Comment: If it's there but you're still getting a "FileError", then you've probably got a path problem. If it's not there then you need to double-check the steps you use to add the file to the gem.

Comment: i think, it is true :) But it doesn't work. My file tree is
lib/editor.rb
lib/lang.rb
lib/messages.rb
lib/utils.rb
lib/images/subhead.png
rmanedit.gemspec

Comment: Why not just look in the directory it specifies and see if the file is there? This is a really simple problem to solve, but first you need to just check if the file is there or not in `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/...` - I mean you haven't definitively answered my question, so I can't provide anymore help.

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my native language. Sometimes i am sloging. I looked /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/.. My all gem files are at /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/my_applicaiton_file